# mysql get column name on the basis of values

Tags: sql

i have a table

```
plu div1 div2 div3 div4
101  3   0    4    0
102  2   4    8    3
103  0   0    0    0
104  5   4    0    1
105  8   6    2    0
```

i want the name of the column with respect to plu where the values of the columns are not zero.
Output should be

```
plu    stores
101    div1,div4
102    div1,div2,div3,div4
103    
104    div1, div2, div3
105    div1, div2, div3
```

Comment: what RDBMS it is mysql/oracle/sqlserver ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach with spaces instead of commas. It may need to trim the  extra comma at the end

```
   select  concat(concat(concat(concat(case when div1!=0 then 'div1,' else ''  end)
    , case when div2!=0 then 'div2,' else '' end)
        , case  when div3!=0 then 'div3,' else  '' end)
            ,case when div4 !=0 then ' div4,' else '' end);
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But actual problem was => there are 81 columns like  div1, div2, div3.......up to ....div81. If you find some optimize solution , please let me know